# search records of a user from last 30 days dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, epoch

my dynamodb structure is somehow for example  my PK and SK is like

**PK =  USR#123ACT#234 and SK = AYT#<epoch_time>**

and my global index are like

**GSi3pk = ACT#234  and GSI3SK = <epoch_time>**

**now case is using global index I want to get data of last 30 days with account_id=234**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query for a specific primary key (of account number) and a timestamp in the last 30 days, you can query with some variant of this:

```
{
    "TableName": "orders",
    "IndexName": "gsi3",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "gsi3pk = :pk AND tstamp BETWEEN :start AND :end",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":pk": {
            "S": "ACT#234"
        },
        ":start": {
            "N": "1651962700"
        },
        ":end": {
            "N": "1654641000"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir for reply . my question is I have only 1 field of time . how I can like query to start and end time ?

Comment: The example query that I included has one timestamp attribute (that I've named `tstamp`). The `:start` and `:end`, if that's what you are referring to, are value placeholders, not attribute names.

Comment: I am confuse about  `tstamp`  named field . I don't have any field named  `tstamp`  . it's `GSI3_UPDATED_ON` . can I use this like  `GSI3_UPDATED_ON`  BETWEEN :start AND :end"

Comment: The name `tstamp` is an example. You didn't indicate what attribute contained the timestamp so I gave you an example.